# Unable to load SQL dependencies for Mono on Linux

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, mono, raspberry-pi

I'm attempting to persuade a Raspberry Pi A+ (running Raspbian Jessie 4.1) to run a small ASP.Net v5 program using Mono. The program runs without issue on a Windows machine, and I've run other, non-database, v5 programs on the same Raspberry Pi.

I've copied the solution folder to the Pi, navigated to the [solutionname]/src/[projectname]/ folder, then run `dnu restore`. All packages are successfully (apparently) installed. As far as I'm aware the next step is to create an initial migration for the SQL DB. I'm attempting to do this using `dnx ef migrations add Initial`, but I'm hitting error messages:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Scaffolding.SqlServerDesignTimeServices,
>   EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design' from assembly ''.
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.ConfigureProviderServices
>   (System.String provider, IServiceCollection services, Boolean
>   throwOnError) <0xb1a55f00 + 0x0002f> in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.Build
>   (Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext context) <0xb1a53758 + 0x00177> in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration
>   (System.String name, System.String outputDir, System.String
>   contextType) <0xb1c71000 + 0x000ef> in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program+Executor+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0
>   () <0xb4432578 + 0x0003f> in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program+Executor.Execute (System.Action
>   action) <0xb44324b8 + 0x0002f> in :0 Could not load
>   type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Scaffolding.SqlServerDesignTimeServices,
>   EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design' from assembly ''.

I'm not sure what to make of the blank assembly in this message. Limited Googling suggested that Linux's case-sensitivity could have been a stumbling block, but I've combed my dependencies and can't see any problems:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
```

Can anyone shed any light on the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the installed version of dnx matches to the one that Visual Studio uses. If you have more than one version installed (type `dnvm list`), you have to select the correct version of dnx before you can execute command line commands.

Taking a look into you `project.json` file, I can see that you're using dnx Version 1.0.0-rc1-final. Please note that this is not the most recent version, Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 brings 1.0.0-rc1-update1.

Try to run `dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final` before using the dnu/dnx commands. That should help.